# Casting numpy dtypes to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

I have numpy array of this kind:

```
>>> attr_table.dtype.descr
[('FID', '<i4'),
 ('Shape', '<f8', (2,)),
 ('PROVINCE', '<i4'),
 ('PROVNAME', '<U60'),
 ('PROVABBR', '<U10'),
 ('NATION', '<i4'),
 ('CNTRYNAME', '<U60'),
 ('CNTRYABBR', '<U10')]
```

if I generate DataFrame from this array, I get:

```
>>> df_tab = pd.DataFrame(attr_table.tolist())
>>> df_tab.dtypes
0     int64
1    object
2     int64
3    object
4    object
5     int64
6    object
7    object
dtype: object
```

Now I'm guessing, if pandas didn't cast those numpy dtypes, perhaps I'm unable too, but as there is dtype parameter in DataFrame function, I thought to try my luck:

```
df_tab = pd.DataFrame(attr_table.tolist(), dtype=attr_table.dtype)
```

which gave me:

```
NotImplementedError: compound dtypes are not implementedin the DataFrame constructor
```

I then tried couple of other variations, like defining a columns and feeding dtype argument with list of tuples describing each column with numpy dtype notation, but I get same error again.

What is the right way to cast types from numpy array to pandas DataFrame?

Comment: even easier: DataFrame.from_records; note that your strings will always end up as object dtype

Comment: OK, thank for the tip. I used DataFrame data as `np.array.tolist()` because otherwise pandas raises `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`. The same happens with `DataFrame.from_records()` and I'm not able to decrypt the message. `attr_table.shape` is (1991,)

Comment: you don't need to convert to a list that will lose the dtypes

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Problem why pandas is raising exception if I don't convert to list is because of 'Shape' record which is itself 2d array. I'll convert it to tuple or something that works with pandas DataFrame. Thanks for your replies, `DataFrame.from_records` casts types correctly.

Comment: yep in general using an embedded array is not is good idea